# Get values from multiple textboxes

Tags: object, textbox, visual-foxpro

I have in VFP9 a form which on init event dynamically create textbox controls. And I have a button on this form whose function is to get the textbox values in an array.  I tried so:

```
`   FOR i=1 TO thisform.Objects.count 
    IF UPPER(thisform.Objects(i).Name) == "TEXTBOX"
    k=k+1
    r(k) = thisform.Objects(i).name.value && here is the problem
    ENDIF 
    ENDFOR `
```

but I don't know how to make reference to textbox properties. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon you probably want something more like

```
FOR i=1 TO thisform.Objects.count 
    IF UPPER(thisform.Objects[i].BaseClass) == "TEXTBOX"
        k=k+1
        r(k) = thisform.Objects(i).name
    ENDIF 
ENDFOR
```

Comment: in this mode you get the name of object, but not the value of it.